# there any effecient way to php date adding using strtotime() without using FUNC date_add () using php below < ver 5.3

Tags: mysql, strtotime, dateadd

Is there any effecient way to  php date adding without using `date_add()`
  using `php < ver 5.3`
Can i use strtotime  integer number to add days . here is my program:

```
$tg12 = DATE ( 'Y-m-d',    strtotime  (  $tg1 )  +  86400       ) ;       // ADD 1 DAY   // REVERSE back to format Human  / reverse  Strtotime()  ;      
$tg13 = DATE ( 'Y-m-d',    strtotime  (  $tg1 )  +  86400  * 2  ) ;      // ADD 1 DAY   // REVERSE back to format Human  / reverse  Strtotime()  ;     
$tg14 = DATE ( 'Y-m-d',    strtotime  (  $tg1 )  +  86400  * 3  ) ;      // ADD 1 DAY   // REVERSE back to format Human  / reverse  Strtotime()  ;
```

**Is the format correct? any suggesttion/IDEAs?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: i get numver 86400 from  24 * 60 * 60   (one day)

Comment: the problem of date time is very classic. but the answer is rather difficult.
no one seems have solutions to this challenges. after a long wait (several months), the  expert of this forum
seems dont have the answer provided. I've got an idea of calculating unix time   and  then  divided by  8400
i.e.  60s x 60 minute x 24 hour  .  is that possible? please answer.